# AVPlayerItemVideoOutput stops delivering frames after seek with video composition

Tags: ios, avfoundation, core-image, avvideocomposition

I want to play a video and process it using Core Image filters. I have the following setup:

- the video as an `AVAsset`
- an `AVPlayer` for controlling the video playback
- the `AVAsset` is passed via `AVPlayerItem` to the player
- the Core Image filters are applied using an `AVMutableVideoComposition` that was initialized with `init(asset:applyingCIFiltersWithHandler:)` and assigned to the player item
- an `AVPlayerItemVideoOutput` is used to get the processed frames using `copyPixelBuffer(forItemTime:itemTimeForDisplay:)`

This works as expected. However, I'm observing strange behavior when seeking backwards on the player using `seek(to:completionHandler:)`: the `AVPlayerItemVideoOutput` suddenly stops delivering new pixel buffers and `hasNewPixelBuffer(forItemTime:)` returns `false`. **But this only happens when the filters applied in the video composition are a bit more expensive.** When using a very simple filter or no filter at all, seeking works as expected.

Inspired by [this technical note](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1966/_index.html) I found a workaround be re-assigning the composition to the player item after the `seek` finished, but this feels very hacky—especially since it's working for simple filter pipelines.

Did anybody encounter this before? Is there anything I need to configure differently?